# How to stream and read from a .tar.gz boto3 in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, encoding, stream, boto3, tar.gz

On S3 there is a JSON file with the following format:

```json
{"field1": "...", "field2": "...", ...}
{"field1": "...", "field2": "...", ...}
{"field1": "...", "field2": "...", ...}
```

It is compressed, in `.tar.gz` format, and its unzipped size is ~30GB, therefore I would like to read it in a streaming fashion.

Using the `aws cli`, I managed to locally do so with the following command:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${FILE_NAME}.tar.gz - | gunzip -c -
```

However, I would like to do it **natively** in `python 3.8`.

Merging various solutions online, I tried the following strategies:

### 1. Uncompressing in-memory file [not working]

```py
import boto3, gzip, json
from io import BytesIO

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
key = 'FILE_NAME.tar.gz'
streaming_iterator = s3.Object('BUCKET_NAME', key).get()['Body'].iter_lines()
first_line = next(streaming_iterator)

gzipline = BytesIO(first_line)
gzipline = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipline)
print(gzipline.read())
```

Which raises

```
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

### 2. Using the external library [`smart_open`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/develop/howto.md) [partially working]

```py
import boto3

for line in open(
    f's3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${FILE_NAME}.tar.gz',
    mode="rb",
    transport_params={"client": boto3.client('s3')},
    encoding="raw_unicode_escape",
    compression=".gz"
):
    print(line)
```

This second solution works discretely well for ASCII characters, but for some reason it also turns non ASCII characters into garbage; e.g.,

- **input**: `\xe5\x9b\xbe\xe6\xa0\x87\xe3\x80\x82`
- **output**: `å\x9b¾æ\xa0\x87ã\x80\x82`
- **expected output**: `图标。`

This leads me to think that the `encoding` I put is wrong, but I literally tried every encoding present in [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) and the only ones that don't lead to an Exception are `raw_unicode_escape`, `unicode_escape` and `palmos` (?), but they all produce garbage.

Any suggestion is welcomed, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return from a call to [`get_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) is a `StreamingBody` object, which as the name implies will allow you to read from the object in a streaming fashion.  However, boto3 does not support seeking on this file object.

While you can pass this object to a `tarfile.open` call, you need to be careful.  There are two caveats.  First, you'll need to tell tarfile that you're passing it a non-seekable streaming object using the `|` character in the open string, and you can't do anything that would trigger a seek, such as attempt to get a list of files first, then operate on these files.

Putting it all together is fairly straight forward, you just need to open a object using boto3, then process each file in the tar file in turn:

```python
# Use boto3 to read the object from S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.get_object(Bucket='example-bucket', Key='path/to/example.tar.gz')
obj = resp['Body']

# Open the tar file, the "|" is important, as it instructs
# tarfile that the fileobj is non-seekable
with tarfile.open(fileobj=obj, mode='r|gz') as tar:
    # Enumerate the tar file objects as we extract data
    for member in tar:
        with tar.extractfile(member) as f:
            # Read each row in turn and decode it
            for row in f:
                row = json.loads(row)
                # Just print out the filename and results in this demo
                print(member.name, row)
```